# Are there plans for improving performance of vector files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, performance

Does anybody know if there are any improvements planned pertaining to the performance of vector files in QGIS?

Right now, a 1 GB file with contour lines needs several minutes to open.

In addition to that I have the suggestion that vector-files shouldn't be refreshed in whole when panning or zooming. This could be avoided through a cache.

Answer (score 0):

There were plans and there was a solution but it is now outdated: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/2037

Try if render caching reduces the pain. When working with bigger datasets, avoid zooming out too far - if possible - and use the possibility to deactivate rendering when possible. As mentioned in the comments, loading the file into PostGIS and adding indexes should help too.